# Steam does not launch on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: games, steam

If I try to launch Steam using the command line, I get this error:

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/steven/.steam/steam to /home/steven/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
/home/steven/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
/home/steven/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
```